# Issue with admin panel

Tags: magento2

I have installed magento in subdomain: `magento.webstite.com`

and enter admin panel name:  `/paneladmin`

When I try access `magento.webstite.com/paneladmin` then I get issue: `Not Found`

I checked in `env.php` and is correct name:

```
 'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'paneladmin'
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to show admin path

```
bin/magento info:adminuri
```

check below URL's to change the admin URL.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html

https://meetanshi.com/blog/change-admin-url-in-magento-2/

Check `mod_rewrite` enable or not if disable then enable it(Apache)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

> Run CLI Commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento ca:cl
php bin/magento ca:fl
Set permission
```

I hope this will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your custom admin URL is set. Please check the path in table core_config_data and use it using the following SQL command:

```
Select path from core_config_data where path like 'admin/url/custom_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way :

**Edit the configuration file :**

**E.g.:** Ubuntu file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

**use the command :** sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

**change the piece of code:**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With below code

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**use the command to restart Apache:** sudo service apache2 restart.

I hope it helps!